# Empty body in fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

frontend:

```
 fetch(location.href, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user: document.getElementById("user").innerText,
    call: "Upvote",
    cname: "comp_name"
  })
},(data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

backend:

```
router.post("/",(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

the response of console.log is just {} instead of the json data

I also tried to log the whole response but the body was still empty and i also tried to check for any bug that might be caused in JSON.stringify by putting it in a variable and then doing the fetch but it didn't help

Comment: You may need a `.then()` after the fetch to extract the data. Currently, you are just passing an anonymous function to the fetch API which does nothing.

```fetch(URL, options, body: {}).then((data) => console.log(data));```

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve what you want, you need to add body parser middleware on the server, then you can send object from the front end.

Here we are importing body-parser and using it as middleware. here you can see how to parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded (means form data). and then you can see how to parse json: `bodyParser.json()`

Notice: im adding the middlewares before the route it self.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

router.post("/",(req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

dont forget to do:

```
npm i body-parser
```

now on the front end you can do this:

```
 fetch(location.href, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: {
    user: document.getElementById("user").innerText,
    call: "Upvote",
    cname: "comp_name"
  }
},(data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

The body parser takes the body from the front end, parseing it to object, and giving you access to the data in req.body.